# Adding Attachment Display Settings in custom media frame

Tags: plugins, posts, plugin-development, images, uploads

I made my own custom media frame :

```
$('.add').bind('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Create the media frame.
    file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Select image to insert',
        button: {
            text: 'Insert',
        },
        multiple: true 
    });
    file_frame.open();
});
```

It opens the media manager alright but Attachment display setting part is missing. How can i get that?

Comment: you can't see an edit option under the image?

Answer (score 3):

Just add

```
frame: 'post',
```

to wp.media attributes.

Comment: Some example with explanation would be great.

Comment: Please check this series http://code.tutsplus.com/series/getting-started-with-the-wordpress-media-uploader--cms-666.

Comment: i tried this and it didnt work